# How to integrate Aspera Sdk into react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to integrate Aspera Sdk into react native android for file transfer??

i want to integrate ASPERA SDK into React native Mobile for file transfer.

what are the steeps to do..

Answer (score 0):

Find IBM Aspera free mobile SDKs here:
https://developer.ibm.com/aspera

Sadly IBM does not yet provide a generic mobile app that can be called by another app, so you have to develop a mobile app using IBM Aspera mobile SDK.